# How to dump a large dask dataframe into sql

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I am hitting the memory when I try to dump my dask dataframe into a local SQLlite database.

```
dd.to_sql(
    "merchange",
    db,
    if_exists="replace",
    index_label="user_id",
)
```

so I thought I can use `map_partitions`.

```
def write_partition_to_sqlite(partition: dd.DataFrame) -> None:
    """Insert the data in the table."""
    partition.to_sql("merchange", db, if_exists="append")

# write each partition to SQL lite
dd_merchange.map_partitions(write_partition_to_sqlite).compute()
```

but still I hit the memory.
I have 64gig RAM; have already lowered the precision of the columns;

In Polars I can do

```
splits = np.array_split(range(0, n_rows), n_chunks)

# For each partition in the DataFrame, convert to pandas and insert
for part in splits:
    with engine.begin() as conn:
        conn.execute(
            pl_df.insert(),
            pl_df.slice(part[0], len(part))
            .to_pandas()
            .to_dict(orient="records"),
        )
```

but if I do the same in Dask, that means, I have to execute `.compute()` on every chunk which takes considerable amount of time too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a similar issue and from the dask documenttion I found out that using `delayed_objects`would solve it....and it did. Here is an example of how to apply this and you can certainly adapt it to you situation:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
from dask.delayed import delayed
from dask import compute
import threading

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'user_id': np.arange(1000000),
    'transaction_amount': np.random.normal(100, 10, size=1000000)
})
dd_merchange = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=4)

conn_local = threading.local()

def get_conn():
    global conn_local
    if not hasattr(conn_local, "conn"):
        conn_local.conn = sqlite3.connect('example2.db')
    return conn_local.conn

def insert_into_sqlite(dataframe, table_name):
    conn = get_conn()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    placeholders = ','.join('?' * len(dataframe.columns))
    insert_statement = f"INSERT INTO {table_name} VALUES ({placeholders})"
    data_to_insert = [tuple(row) for row in dataframe.values]
    
    cursor.execute(f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table_name} ({', '.join(dataframe.columns)});")
    
    cursor.executemany(insert_statement, data_to_insert)
    conn.commit()

@delayed
def process_partition(partition, table_name):
    insert_into_sqlite(partition, table_name)

delayed_objects = []
for partition in dd_merchange.to_delayed():
    delayed_objects.append(process_partition(partition, "merchange"))

compute(*delayed_objects)
```

Comment: I ended up walking away from dask - but your solutions looks reasonable. thanks for sharing and spending time on this.